# ¿Por qué los if no hacen la comparación con decimales?

Tags: c

¿Por qué en mis `if` sólo compara los números enteros y los decimales no?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void NombreAlumnos();
float Calificaciones(float);
float Promedio(float);
void MensajePromedioEsp(float);
void MensajePormedioMat(float);


main()
{
    float calific=0.0;
    float calific2=0.0;
    float calific3=0.0;
    float calific4=0.0;
    float calific5=0.0;
    float calific6=0.0;
    float su=0.0;
    float promd;
    float promd2=0.0;
    float promd3=0.0;
    float promd4=0.0;
    float promd5=0.0;
    float promd6=0.0;

    printf("BIENVENIDO\npor favor siga las instrucciones como se le indican\n");
    NombreAlumnos();

    printf("**CALIFICACIONES DE ESPAÑOL**\n");
    calific=Calificaciones(su);
    promd=Promedio(calific);
    MensajePromedioEsp(promd);

    printf("**CALIFICACIONES DE MATEMATICAS**\n");
    calific2=Calificaciones(su);
    promd2=Promedio(calific2);

    printf("**CALIFICACIONES DE EXPLORACION DE LA NATURALEZA Y LA SOCIEDAD**\n");
    calific3=Calificaciones(su);
    promd3=Promedio(calific3);

    printf("**CALIFICACIONES DE FORMACION CIVICA Y ETICA**\n");
    calific4=Calificaciones(su);
    promd4=Promedio(calific4);

    printf("**CALIFICACIONES DE EDUCACION FISICA**\n");
    calific5=Calificaciones(su);
    promd5=Promedio(calific5);

    printf("**CALIFICACIONES DE EDUCACION ARTISTICA**\n");
    calific6=Calificaciones(su);

    getchar();
    //getchar();
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

void NombreAlumnos()
{
    char PrimerNombre[20];
    char SegundoNombre[20];
    char PrimerApellido[20];
    char SegundoApellido[20];

    printf("\nColoque el primer apellido del alumno y de ENTER\n");
    scanf("%s",&PrimerApellido);

    printf("Coloque el segundo apellido del alumno y de ENTER\n");
    scanf("%s",&SegundoApellido);

    printf("Coloque el primer nombre del alumno y de ENTER\n");
    scanf("%s",&PrimerNombre);

    printf("Coloque el segundo nombre del alumno y de ENTER\n(en caso de no tener coloque un . y continue)\n");
    scanf("%s",&SegundoNombre);

    printf("El nombre del alumno es: %s %s %s %s\n\n",PrimerApellido,SegundoApellido,PrimerNombre,SegundoNombre);
}

float Calificaciones(float suma)
{
    float Calif[6];
    int i=0;

    printf("\nIngresa calificaciones\n");
    for(i=0; i<=5; i++)
    {
      printf("Bimestre %d:\t",i+1);
      scanf("%f",&Calif[i]);
      suma=suma+Calif[i];
    }
    return suma;
}

float Promedio(float sum)
{
    printf("\nEl promedio es %.1f\n\n",sum/6);
    return sum/6;
}

void MensajePromedioEsp(float p)
{
    if (p==6.0) printf("\nPone atención en las características de lo que observa. Apoyar el uso de los Adjetivos y frases adjetivas para describir cantidad, tamaño y otros atributos físicos.\n\n");
    if (p==6.1) printf("\nDescribe los sucesos que vive en su contexto social. Reforzar las Palabras que indican secuencia temporal (primero, después, en la segunda semana, después de cinco días, finalmente).\n\n");
    if (p==6.2) printf("\nExpresa lo que siente, ve, vive en su entorno por medio de escritura libre. Continuar con la Correspondencia entre escritura  y oralidad.\n\n");
    if (p==6.3) printf("\nUso adecuado de la ortografía. Apoyar la Escritura convencional de palabras con dígrafos ( ll , rr , ch ) y sílabas trabadas ( plátano , trompo , piedra , globo ).\n\n");
    if (p==6.4) printf("\nIdentifica la necesidad de las reglas ortográficas al escribir. Reforzar el uso de las Mayúsculas al inicio de párrafo  y en nombres propios.\n\n");
    if (p==6.5) printf("\nUtiliza palabras que indican secuencia temporal. Continuar recabando Información que es recuperada en distintas fuentes.\n\n");
    if (p==6.6) printf("\nComprende la función de la moraleja. Consolidar en ejercicios las Características de las fábulas\n\n");
    if (p==6.7) printf("\nIdentifica la secuencia de acciones  y personajes principales en una fábula. Fortalecer la Anticipación de la moraleja de una fábula.\n\n");
    if (p==6.8) printf("\nInterpreta el contenido de una fábula. Reafirmar la Interpretación del significado de las fábulas.\n\n");
    if (p==6.9) printf("\nConsulta diccionarios para resolver dudas ortográficas. Mantener el habito de la auto corrección\n\n");
    if (p==7.0) printf("\nLocaliza información específica en fuentes consultadas. Resaltar la Importancia de contrastar información  en diversos textos\n\n");
    if (p==7.1) printf("\nIdentifica las características generales  de los textos expositivos. Auxiliar la Selección de información acerca  de un tema.\n\n");
    if (p==7.2) printf("\nRespeta la ortografía y puntuación convencionales de palabras al escribir  un texto. Reforzar las Características y función de las listas  y las tablas.\n\n");
    if (p==7.3) printf("\nEmplea listas y tablas para organizar información. Apoyar los Criterios de reuso\n\n;");
    if (p==7.4) printf("\nElaborar un plan de trabajo  con un propósito determinado. Apoyar la Forma de organizar la información  en un plan de trabajo.\n\n");
    if (p==7.5) printf("\nUtiliza el lenguaje escrito para diferentes propósitos. Apoyar la Correspondencia entre escritura y oralidad.\n\n");
    if (p==7.6) printf ("\nEmplea adjetivos para la descripción  de paisajes. Reforzar las Características y función de los textos descriptivos.\n");
    if (p==7.7) printf("\nIdentifica palabras adecuadas para escribir frases. Elaboración de preguntas para guiar  su búsqueda de información\n\n");
    if (p==7.8) printf("\nRecupera conocimientos previos para responder a preguntas. Consulta de fuentes de información.\n\n");
    if (p==7.9) printf("\nEmplea las convenciones ortográficas de palabras escritas a partir de un texto modelo.  Ortografía convencional de palabras escritas tomadas de un modelo.\n\n");
    if (p==8.0) printf("\nIdentifica y corrige errores  de concordancia de género y número,  y reiteraciones innecesarias en sus textos.   Mayúsculas al inicio de párrafo  y en nombres propios.\n\n");
    if (p==8.1) printf("\nIdentifica la función de las reseñas.  Reseñar cuentos recuperando su trama\n\n");
    if (p==8.2) printf("\nEmplea escritura convencional de palabras con dígrafos o sílabas trabadas.   Características y función de las notas para resumir información.");
    if (p==8.3) printf("\nRecupera información oral por medio  de notas.  Identificación de las palabras clave para  la comprensión de un tema.\n\n");
    if (p==8.4) printf("\nComplementa la descripción del proceso observado con la información que provee alguna fuente de consulta. Registro de información en nota\n\n");
    if (p==8.5) printf("\nUtiliza palabras que indican secuencia temporal. Información recuperada en distintas fuentes.\n\n");
    if (p==8.6) printf("\nUtiliza la información registrada  en notas para dar cuenta de un proceso observado. Registro de la información sobre  un proceso.\n\n");
    if (p==8.7) printf("\nColabora en la realización de tareas conjuntas. Escritura convencional de palabras  con dígrafos ( ll , rr , ch ) y sílabas trabadas\n\n");
    if (p==8.8) printf("\nSelecciona palabras o frases adjetivas para elaborar descripciones.  Interpretación de indicaciones  y descripciones.\n\n");
    if (p==8.9) printf("\nPone atención en las características de lo que observa. Apoyar el uso de los Adjetivos y frases adjetivas para describir cantidad, tamaño y otros atributos físicos.\n\n");
    if (p==9.0) printf("\nDescribe los sucesos que vive en su contexto social. Reforzar las Palabras que indican secuencia temporal (primero, después, en la segunda semana, después de cinco días, finalmente).\n\n");
    if (p==9.1) printf("\nExpresa lo que siente, ve, vive en su entorno por medio de escritura libre. Continuar con la Correspondencia entre escritura  y oralidad\n\n");
    if (p==9.2) printf("\nUso adecuado de la ortografía. Apoyar la Escritura convencional de palabras con dígrafos ( ll , rr , ch ) y sílabas trabadas ( plátano , trompo , piedra , globo ).\n\n");
    if (p==9.3) printf("\nIdentifica la necesidad de las reglas ortográficas al escribir. Reforzar el uso de las Mayúsculas al inicio de párrafo  y en nombres propios.\n\n");
    if (p==9.4) printf("\nUtiliza palabras que indican secuencia temporal. Continuar recabando Información que es recuperada en distintas fuentes.\n\n");
    if (p==9.5) printf("\nComprende la función de la moraleja. Consolidar en ejercicios las Características de las fábulas.\n\n");
    if (p==9.6) printf("\nIdentifica la secuencia de acciones  y personajes principales en una fábula. Fortalecer la Anticipación de la moraleja de una fábula.\n\n");
    if (p==9.7) printf("\nInterpreta el contenido de una fábula. Reafirmar la Interpretación del significado de las fábulas.\n\n");
    if (p==9.8) printf("\nConsulta diccionarios para resolver dudas ortográficas. Mantener el habito de la auto corrección\n\n");
    if (p==9.9) printf("\nLocaliza información específica en fuentes consultadas. Resaltar la Importancia de contrastar información  en diversos textos.\n\n");
    if (p==10)  printf("\nIdentifica las características generales  de los textos expositivos. Auxiliar la Selección de información acerca  de un tema.\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Hola @Angel. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Si bien se puede entender tu pregunta, ¿no crees que sería más práctico reducir tu problema a unas pocas líneas de código? ¿Es necesario **todo** el código que publicaste? La idea es que las preguntas tengan un **[mcve]**, y no pegar todo esperando que alguien revise cada una de las líneas hasta ver a qué te estás refiriendo. Ayudanos a ayudarte: unas pocas líneas, el resultado obtenido, y el resultado esperado. Eso haría que tu pregunta obtenga mejores respuestas y más rápido.

Comment: Porque un `float` nunca va  ser `9.900000000 ...` exactamente ...

Comment: @leonbloy Ese es el motivo, pero creo que no responde a cómo solucionarlo en C.

Comment: @Mariano Discrepo. Lo que necesita el que pregunta es entender el problema. Solucionarlo (en este caso) es secundario.

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacer un cast a float en tu numero

```
void MensajePromedioEsp(float p)
{


    if (p==(float)6.0) printf("\nPone atención en las características de lo que observa. Apoyar el uso de los Adjetivos y frases adjetivas para describir cantidad, tamaño y otros atributos físicos.\n\n");
    if (p==(float)6.1) printf("\nDescribe los sucesos que vive en su contexto social. Reforzar las Palabras que indican secuencia temporal (primero, después, en la segunda semana, después de cinco días, finalmente).\n\n");
    if (p==(float)6.2) printf("\nExpresa lo que siente, ve, vive en su entorno por medio de escritura libre. Continuar con la Correspondencia entre escritura  y oralidad.\n\n");
    if (p==(float)6.3) printf("\nUso adecuado de la ortografía. Apoyar la Escritura convencional de palabras con dígrafos ( ll , rr , ch ) y sílabas trabadas ( plátano , trompo , piedra , globo ).\n\n");
}
```

o puedes  multiplicarlo por 10 y convertirlo a int

```
void MensajePromedioEsp(float p)
{       
    int n=(int)(p*10);
    if (n==60) printf("\nPone atención en las características de lo que observa. Apoyar el uso de los Adjetivos y frases adjetivas para describir cantidad, tamaño y otros atributos físicos.\n\n");
    if (n==61) printf("\nDescribe los sucesos que vive en su contexto social. Reforzar las Palabras que indican secuencia temporal (primero, después, en la segunda semana, después de cinco días, finalmente).\n\n");
    }
```